# Wait for DOM to finalize manipulations before calling prompt

Tags: javascript, html

The page needs to be rendered before the prompt is called. In current implementation, `prompt(...)` interrupts DOM manipulation and `hint` is shown only after user clicks OK on prompt message box.

Although `el.innerHTML = 'Please, reply to prompt';` is called before `var res = prompt('Hello world');`, the HTML element with `id='hint'` won't be updated until user hits OK on prompt message box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callNativeApp() {
        console.log('callNativeApp called');
        try {
            // Show hint message
            var el = document.getElementById('hint'); 
            el.innerHTML = 'Please, reply to prompt';

            // Call prompt            
            var res = prompt('Hello world');

            // Write result of prompt reply to html
            document.getElementById('prompt-call-output').innerHTML = res;
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
        }
    }
</script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="callNativeApp()">Call native app</button>
        <p id="hint"></p>
        <p id="prompt-call-output"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to change current code, so the page renders first. And only after that prompt is called()? E.g. Somehow force DOM tree to update(refresh) before prompt call?

Timeout solution for calling `var res = prompt('Hello world');` like

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var res = prompt('Hello world');
    document.getElementById('prompt-call-output').innerHTML = res;
}, 100);
```

is not applicable as our current codebase relies on sequence of commands that goes after `prompt(...)` call.

Screen that shows that `hint` is not shown when prompt is called, even though text hint setting is called before calling prompt:
[image]

And `hint` is only shown when prompt window is closed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the issues regarding prompt, alert, and confirm messages, they block javascript execution since the browser waits for user interaction, also are considered bad [UX implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#Notes):

> Dialog boxes are modal windows; they prevent the user from accessing
>   the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed.
>   For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a
>   dialog box (or modal window).

one of the solution to this is to implement [your own prompts dialog](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/async-dialogs.html), in this link from [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/async-dialogs.html) the address it using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with async dialogs:

```js
function promptPromise(message) {
  var dialog       = document.getElementById('dialog');
  var input        = dialog.querySelector('input');
  var okButton     = dialog.querySelector('button.ok');

  dialog.querySelector('.message').innerHTML = String(message);
  dialog.className = '';

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    dialog.addEventListener('click', function handleButtonClicks(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') { return; }
      dialog.removeEventListener('click', handleButtonClicks);
      dialog.className = 'hidden';
      if (e.target === okButton) {
        resolve(input.value);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('User cancelled'));
      }
    });
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('action');
  var output = document.getElementById('prompt');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    promptPromise('What is your name?').then(function(name) {
      output.innerHTML = '' + name;
    })
    .catch(function() {
      output.innerHTML = '¯\\_(ツ)_/¯';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Async Dislogs Example</title>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.0.5/bluebird.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var time = document.getElementById('time-stamp');
      clockTick();
      setInterval(clockTick, 1000);
      function clockTick() {
        time.innerHTML = '' + new Date();
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #dialog {
      width: 200px;
      margin: auto;
      border: thin solid black;
      padding: 10px;
      background: lightgreen;
    }
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>The current time is <span id="time-stamp"></span>.</p>
  <p>Your name is <span id="prompt"></span>.</p>
  <button id="action">Set Name</button>
  <div id="dialog" class="hidden">
    <div class="message">foobar</div>
    <input type="text">
    <div>
      <button class="ok">Ok</button>
      <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For your code snippet the implementation would be something like this:

```js
function promptPromise(message) {
  var dialog       = document.getElementById('dialog');
  var input        = dialog.querySelector('input');
  var okButton     = dialog.querySelector('button.ok');

  dialog.querySelector('.message').innerHTML = String(message);
  dialog.className = '';

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    dialog.addEventListener('click', function handleButtonClicks(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') { return; }
      dialog.removeEventListener('click', handleButtonClicks);
      dialog.className = 'hidden';
      if (e.target === okButton) {
        resolve(input.value);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('User cancelled'));
      }
    });
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('action');
  var output = document.getElementById('hint');
  var el = document.getElementById('hint'); 
  
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.innerHTML = 'Please, reply to prompt';
    promptPromise('Hello world').then(function(name) {
      document.getElementById('prompt-call-output').innerHTML = '' + name;
    })
    .catch(function() {
      output.innerHTML = '¯\\_(ツ)_/¯';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="action">Call native app</button>
        <p id="hint"></p>
        <p id="prompt-call-output"></p>
        <div id="dialog" class="hidden">
          <div class="message">foobar</div>
          <input type="text">
          <div>
            <button class="ok">Ok</button>
            <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```